# Is there a way to get the height of a div set to `overflow-y: auto`

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a `div` set to `overflow-y: auto`. Can I inspect what would be the divs height with its content without `overflow-y: auto`?

I want to keep `overflow-y: auto` and know what is the height of `div` like there is no `overflow-y: auto`

### More specific:

I have a chat window. Chat contains messages as text and images.
Chat div is set to `overflow-y: auto` and at the bottom inside the `div` I have another `div` which holds `ref={scrollToBottomRef}`

Then I have `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottomRef.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  });
```

This works well. When messages are loaded I get the scroll down to the bottom.
The issue occurs when the message contains an image. Then I get the scroll down to the bottom before the images are rendered thus after a split of a second the scroll bumps up from the bottom.

How do I work around that?

Comment: Try `element.scrollHeight` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Comment: offsetHeight...

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of `Element.scrollHeight`, as pointed out by @Scrimothy. It works on just about every browser with no issues. It includes padding, but not border or margin. If the content doesn't fill the whole div, it returns the div's height.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `scrollIntoView` in my useEffect. It works as expected without `smooth scroll`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottomRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  });
```